How we integrate to get the following inequality $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\|U\|_2^2+\nu\|\omega\|_2^2\leq|\int U^xU^y| $
The vorticity $\omega=\partial_x U^y-\partial_y U^x$ solves
\begin{align}\label{vorticity}
    \left\{\begin{array}{l}
\partial_t \omega+y \partial_x \omega+U \cdot \nabla \omega=\nu \Delta \omega \\
U=\nabla^{\perp}\Delta^{-1}\omega \\
\left.\omega\right|_{t=0}=\omega_{\mathrm{in}}(x, y)
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
where $\nabla^{\perp}=(-\partial_y , \partial_x)$.
The velocity satisfies the momentum equation
\begin{align}
   U_t+y\partial_xU+(U^y,0)+U\cdot\nabla U=-\nabla P+\nu\Delta U
\end{align}
My question is: How we integrate to get the following inequality
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\|U\|_2^2+\nu\|\omega\|_2^2\leq|\int U^xU^y|\leq\|U\|_2^2
\end{align}
Thanks for your help!!!

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.
